# Cannot start cassandra: numactl: execution in CentOS 6

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, java, cassandra

I trying to install [Datastax Apache Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/install/installTarball_t.html) with OpenJDK

```
# java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.4.1.el6_5-x86_64 u51-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

# mkdir -p /var/log/cassandra /var/lib/cassandra
# chown -R `whoami` /var/log/cassandra /var/lib/cassandra

# curl -L http://downloads.datastax.com/community/dsc.tar.gz | tar xz
# cd dsc-cassandra-2.*
```

When I run cassandra in foreground I get this error:

```
# bin/cassandra -f
numactl: execution of `': No such file or directory
```

Setting the JAVA_HOME seems doesn't work too:

```
# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/jdk

# JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk bin/cassandra -f
numactl: execution of `': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set your `JAVA_HOME` variable. That should fix this.

Comment: It doesn't work: # echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/jdk
# JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk bin/cassandra -f
numactl: execution of `': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Append the `PATH` and set the `JAVA_HOME` variables as below. Please see step 4 of *Installing Oracle JDK on RHEL-based Systems* [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installJdkRHEL.html).

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/java/latest/bin"
set JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
```